# The simplest Paint program isn't working in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm plowing through the Dietle C# book one page at a time and I'm stuck.

On page 555, there's the most basic drawing program you can imagine. As you move your mouse around, it's supposed to draw an ellipse on the screen.

Well, mine doesn't.

I've checked everything possible. I've gone onto the Dietel website and downloaded the code and tried that. I think I'm doing something wrong outside of the text-based programming. I mean, there are settings and stuff in the properties windows.

I think I got it all right, but nothing seems to work.  But obviously I don't have it all right or it would work.

The full code is a bit longer than what I have below, but even this simplified code doesn't work.  It's supposed to draw ellipses any time you have the mouse on the screen. Studio Express does a nice job of catching a lot of syntax errors, but of course it can't catch logic errors.  Any ideas as to what's wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                graphics.FillEllipse(
                    new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first thing to do is always to put a breakpoint at the critical line(s) and check if a) you actually reach it and b) the data there are as expected. So put a breakpoint on the fillellispe line and report back.  (if you don't hit it when you move the mouse over the form the event is not hooked up.)

Comment: Your code as posted works fine. Make sure the MouseMove is hooked up! Either (preferrable) in the event properties tab of the form or as Ibki shows you in the Form constructor..

Comment: Btw: adding this line before the FillEllipse will make the 'program' work a lot nicer : `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)`

Comment: `this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);` is what was needed.  This wasn't in the book.  I suppose if I look hard enough in the chapter, the writer may have mentioned it.  I'm going to check out how to do it the event properties tab.  I don't know how yet.  Thanks all!!

Comment: It was not in the book, I guess, because the author somewhere told the readers how to add this handler in the normal and recommended way: open the Form's__ event property tab__ to the right, search for the `mousemove` event and __doubleclick__ it. Doing it this way the line gets added to the form_designer.cs file, where it belongs.. - since it was baseically Ibki's answer you should _accept_ it.

Comment: I'm new to the forum, and I'm not sure where the accept button is.  Do I even have enough rep points?  I'd like to thank him here in this comment though:  Thank you, Ibki.  :)

Comment: This is interesting.  When I went to the right and followed TaW's advice, it auto generates a line of code. I see that there's a little difference between what the auto-generator makes and what I typed in: `Form1_MouseMove_1` isn't the same as `Form1_MouseMove` which is from the book.

Comment: That's because the usual name (from the book) was already in the code. To clean it up one sometimes has to go to the ..Designer.cs and delete or change an event handler there. (__very__ carefully!!) - So you should 1) go there and __change__ the generated handler name to Form_MouseMove and then go to the event tab and make the same change there. then all should work as before and you can delete the generated event stub Form_MouseMove_1 from the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MouseMove Event??

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<IDrawAble> shapes = new List<IDrawAble>();

    private MyEllipse currentlyDrawing;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentlyDrawing = new MyEllipse() { X1 = e.X, Y1 = e.Y, X2 = e.X, Y2 = e.Y };
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shapes.Add(currentlyDrawing);
        currentlyDrawing = null;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        foreach (var item in shapes)
        {
            item.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
        if (currentlyDrawing != null)
        {
            currentlyDrawing.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentlyDrawing != null)
        {
            currentlyDrawing.X2 = e.X;
            currentlyDrawing.Y2 = e.Y;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

class MyEllipse : IDrawAble
{
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int X2 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }


    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), X1, Y1, X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1);
    }
}

interface IDrawAble
{
    void Draw(Graphics g);
}
```

Make sure all eventhandlers are hooked to the events of the form.
To get rid of the flickering set the DoubleBuffered Property of the Form to true.

Comment: If you want to draw many shapes i would draw in a bitmap instead though.

Answer (score 0):

What is it doing now?

Just to Add.

1. Make sure your event  MouseMove is mapped with the Method Form1_MouseMove
2. In the Method Hieght and weight are **20**  which means it is circle and not eclipse.
3. for to debug first replace e.X and e.Y with number in below snippet it is 0

   ```
      SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

       // Create location and size of ellipse. 
       float x = 0.0F;
       float y = 0.0F;
       float width = 200.0F;
       float height = 100.0F;         


       using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
       {
           graphics.FillEllipse(redBrush, x, y, width, height);
       }
   ```